# Facebook Canvas Application: iFrame equivalent of <FB:SWF>?

Tags: flash, facebook, iframe

I need to embed a flash application(that will access FB API from within) in Facebook Canvas page.

If I use , some FB related details(like session key) will be automatically passed to the flash. But since, FBML is going to be [deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap), I want to use iFrame. Is there any way to pass those variable automatically or do I have to retrieve them in PHP and pass it to flash through loadvars?

Also, if I have to do it manually, is there any documentation for the php sdk 2.1 ? (already searched about it a lot, and I think there is no doc nor tutorial for 2.1)

thanks

-Saiyasodharan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to pass the information via loadvars. There is no specific documentation on passing the variables to flash, but if you specify what information you want to pass then I can help clarify how to acquire it

Comment: apologies... tis comment section s too short to post.. so i posted as new answer

Answer (score 0):

I thought so... thx for de confirmation

to create a session in as3, I need to create a facebooksessionutil object, which requires
apikey,
secretkey,
fb_sig_session_key,
fb_sig_ss,
fb_sig_user,
as_app_name
and probabaly some other variables too

the last four variables are in facebooksessionutil class, which is a part of facebook as3 api. I took them from the

source and am not sure, whether they are just strings or real objects containing all the details...

I think the facebook as3 api is based on old version, since it requires apikey and secretkey, whereas the api

requires appid and secretkey. Maybe I should wait, till the facebook as3 api is updated to reflect the changes.

anyway, thanks :-)

Comment: fb_sig_session_key, fb_sig_ss, fb_sig_user are all deprecated, you need to use the new access_token instead. Try looking at the way the PHP sdk does it's authentication to see what I mean

Comment: hmm.. then the facebook as3 api s not gonna work, if it cant get those variables... i think i could wait some more time, till the new version of facebook as3 api is released based on the new OAuth authentication system... thx for ur info :)